# Intermittent battery light after new battery and alternator

Tags: ford, alternator, warning-light, intermittent-problems, galaxy

I had a small fuel leak on my 2009 Ford Galaxy which got into my alternator and killed it. It then drained the battery. I got the leak fixed, got a new battery fitted and a new alternator fitted (presumably a refurb).

However on every few startups my alternator appears to be going into default charge (had RAC come out to confirm this). I've had the car back to Halford's who fitted the alternator twice who both times say they found a loose connection and that it was sorted, but this morning it came on again.

The car either starts up fine and the alternator gives out 14.8 V, or it starts bad only giving 13.7 V causing the light to come on. Also, the connection on top of the alternator has 2 male pins whereas the connector on my car only has a female connector for 1 of them.

Comment: I would consider 14.8 V to be on the high side and the 13.7 V output is normal. Are you sure you didn't mix up the two readings?

Comment: Just double checked, definitely 14.7 with no battery light, 13.7 when on. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I'm wondering if this could be a fault on the smart charge wiring side?

Comment: Do you mean the voltage regulator? That is a possibility, although I'm inclined to think that something is fundamentally wrong with the alternator's setup. You need to figure out if the wiring is according to the car's specification and rule out things like a slipping belt first

Comment: i read this: http://www.valeoservice.com/data/master/webfile/2945759434DDE6E8714173.pdf which made me wonder. The car had no issues with charging whatsoever until this swap.